# QGIS CPP multi-platform plugin deployment

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

We're starting to look at porting some of our plugins over from ArcMap to QGIS and we're pretty excited about it.

Currently everything we have is written in C++ so it would be nice to use that on QGIS too.

So far the resources that I've found: [Writing C++ Plugins](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Writing_C++_Plugins_%5BNew%5D), [QGIS Coding and Compilation Guide](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.1.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf) seem good but they didn't answer my specific questions.

**Can C++ plugins be deployed in the plugin store?** If so, how do you do this in a multi-platform environment? Is there a cookbook for deploying C++ plugins across platforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally discouraged to write c++ QGIS plugins, for the following reasons:

- They can't be distributed via the plugin library (only python plugins with no binary dependencies are accepted)
- The c++ API is not stable between QGIS releases (including point releases), so you need to update and recompile c++ plugins for each QGIS version used. (In contrast, the PyQGIS API is fixed for the duration of a major release. Eg PyQGIS plugins written for QGIS 2.0 should still work under 2.14).
- Cross compilation of c++ plugins (outside of the main QGIS source tree) is difficult. You'll need a separate build environment for each targeted platform and separate binaries for each.

It's worth noting that even in the QGIS codebase itself there is a strong movement away from c++ plugins to either including code directly within core QGIS or to use of python plugins.

Comment: Awesome. This was my impression too after a bit more research. Nice to see it outlined so clearly though.

Comment: So here's my suggestion: if it's functionality which you think could be of widespread use, then explore getting those parts merged into the QGIS code. Then port the rest to python. Ie if you've got specific c++ methods for handling geometries, operations etc there's a good chance these could be of value in the main codebase and this would also simplify the porting process somewhat!

Comment: Good suggestion. Thinking this way is relatively new to us since we've been ESRI / ArcMap / Closed Source developers for a while but I love the idea of giving back.  There's a good chance that everything we need is already inside QGIS so python seem like the right way to go for sure.